# Is it good for my courier using php and laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using php and Laravel.
Is is good to build my courier?

I know this is ridiculous but i wonder.

modern php is much better than before.
but i'm still wonder using php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it is still good using php especially laravel.

First, php framework (laravel) using **MVC Architecture** that easy to use, and many tutorials there.

And then, laravel have a feature called **Eloquent ORM** for easy interaction with your app database

Comment: thanks. it makes me clear to understand.